# Using hamburger menu symbol/icon by its unicode in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, icons, hamburger-menu

I am trying to display a hamburger menu symbol/icon in a button control in Winforms C# using the symbol's unicode. I tried google-searching but all the results were referring to hamburger menu unicodes for UWP, CSS, Xamarin, etc.. NOT C# Winforms.

The reason why i need the hamburger menu unicode to implement in C# Winforms is the ease/simplicity of changing the symbol's ForeColor via code or properties Tab, rather than having to upload a new image each time i need a different symbol or icon color.

Is there a unicode for a hamburger menu symbol for implementing in C# Winforms or I'll have to upload a new image each time i need a hamburger menu icon with a different color?

Thank you.

Comment: A Unicode value works the same, whether it's UWP, CSS, Xamarin, Java, or any other language being used. It's hard to say what you've tried doesn't work, because you've not included what you've tried. Set the button's font to one that includes that symbol, set the button's caption to that value, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying that i should set the button's font to a specific font to display the symbol. Probably that's what i was missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the button text to the Unicode value in code like so...

```
button1.Text = char.ConvertFromUtf32('\u2630'); // "☰";
```

Or you can paste the symbol in the button's Text property in the designer properties list.

Comment: This works even with different font types. Thank you!